# IIS 8.5 only serving dynamic pages (MVC) locally. Externally only serving static pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8.5

I can't figure out this problem. I have an MVC5 site and works perfectly on development and also under localhost on a production server (Windows Server 2012 R2). 
However, when accessing it externally via its hostname it only serves static content, none of the dynamic pages are working, routing doesn't work and just times out!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you ensured all the prerequisites are installed on the server? Post the error detail/image if possible.

Comment: Shaun, there are no errors, the site just times-out. All the requirements have been satisfied. Like I said, when you run the site on localhost under the production server everything just works. It is also not a DNS problem because I can get to static resources using the fully qualified URL.